# how to add style to a table that i want export to excel from angular

Tags: angular

I want to export a table from angular but the libraries I have seen only export the data without style, I would like the table that is exported to have borders and color.

Is there a library that can do it in angular?

Comment: [SheetJs - XLSX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) could be helpful

Comment: I tried to do it but I can't border the table